# How to seperately disable/ enable multiple submit buttons in a form?

Tags: html, angular, forms, button, form-control

I generate multiple forms in my angular app with `*ngFor` and **all** the submit buttons get disabled/ enabled when I change just a single input field.
I want the button of a corresponding input field to disable/ enable when **only** the input field of the correpsonding form changed, not when **any** input field of any form changes.
I can't come up with a solution or an alternative right now. Any idea?

My html code:

```
<mat-card *ngIf="myText">
  <h1 mat-header class="center">My texts</h1>
  <mat-card-content>
    <div *ngFor="let item of myText">
      <h3 mat-subheader class="center">myText {{ item.index + 1 }}</h3>
      <p class="message">{{ item.textmessage }}</p>
      <form [formGroup]="myTextForm" class="myText-form" (ngSubmit)="sendPrompt(item.index)">
        <mat-form-field class="full-width" *ngIf="!error">
          <mat-label>Respond to text</mat-label>
          <textarea
            matInput
            cdkTextareaAutosize
            cdkAutosizeMinRows="3"
            cdkAutosizeMaxRows="20"
            formControlName="prompt"
            required="true"
          ></textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
        <p>
          <button mat-raised-button class="btn" color="primary" [disabled]="myTextForm.invalid" type="submit">
            Respond
          </button>
          <button
            mat-raised-button
            color="accent"
            [cdkCopyToClipboard]="item.textmessage"
          >
            Copy to clipboard
          </button>
        </p>        
      </form>
      <mat-divider *ngIf="item.index + 1 < myText.length"></mat-divider>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Any help or tips are much appreciated.

EDIT: Daniel Vágners answer did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention that I've tried to set a dynamic name to the forms, so they are treated all separetely, but I did not work.

Comment: The problem is that you're only using a formgroup. Create for each a single formgroup and iterate over the formgroups.

Comment: @heaxyh the input field and button (in combination) should belong to a single text message. There might be multiple text messages, thats why I iterate through myText. I'm not sure why I should iterate again through the formgroup, since there must only be a single combination of input field and button for each text message. Or maybe I'm just missunderstanding your comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: An example to what I mentioned in my first comment: formGroup]="myTextForm{{item.index}}" But this does not work (Parser Error: Unexpected token '{' )...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great to receive the component.ts corresponding to the HTML.

Based on what I know from you and if I understand correctly. I suggest that the problem here is that you're using the same FormGroup for every form in your loop (myTextForm). Create a separate FormGroup for each form. This would isolate the validation for each form, and each submit button.

First of all create aray and init form

```
myTextForms: FormArray = new FormArray([]);

// init form mostly on ngOnInit or when your data are ready
initForms() {
  for (const item of this.myText) {
    this.myTextForms.push(new FormGroup({
      'prompt': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    }));
  }
}
```

After that modify your formGroup and submitButton so it will use the FormArray and accesses each FormGroup by index.

```
<form [formGroup]="myTextForms.at(i)" class="myText-form" (ngSubmit)="sendPrompt(item.index)">
```

and

```
 <button mat-raised-button class="btn" color="primary" [disabled]="myTextForms.at(i).invalid" type="submit">
        Respond
      </button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can not implement your function (Argument of type 'FormGroup<{ prompt: FormControl<string | null>; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.).

Comment: The component.ts corresponding to the HTML is rather short (without the button function): 
`myTextForm = new FormGroup({
    prompt: new FormControl(),
  });`

Comment: Its working for me. Try to add type to myTextForms: FormArray = new FormArray([]);

Btw: if you still have some issue, send me your code on stackblitz :)

Comment: Thank you, Daniel Vágner! It worked with type any. :)